# tikz shorten with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

in circuitikz double bipoles are drawn as nodes (not via `to[...]`), but sometimes one needs voltage arrows for double bipoles as well.

As I didn't find a way to do this directly (with circuitikz), I decided to do it manually. So I came up with `\draw (pol.B1) to node[currarrow] {} (pol.B2);`. With this path the arrow obviously goes from wire to wire which is kinda ugly.

So I tried to shorten the arrow and came up with

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core] (pol) {};
    \draw[shorten <=.5cm, red] (pol.B1) to node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} (pol.B2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core] (pol) {};
    \draw[blue] (pol.B1) to[shorten <=.5cm] node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} (pol.B2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in
[image: Result]

well I guess the blue try does not work as `shorten ...` is a key that has to be specified at `\draw[...]` and not at `to[...]` since it shortens the whole path, not a segment of the path.

Just to be sure, is this right?

But then I'm still confused by the lines at (1) and (2) why are they there? (without `shorten` these lines are not present) And how can I get rid of them?

EDIT: And in addition the question, is there a way to shorten the segment created by `to` (to avoid that one always has to begin a new path to create the arrow)?
I came up with

```tex
\tikzset{
    skip/.style={
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) --
            ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!(\tikztostart)$)
            \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way.

Comment: You are right --- it dos not work because `currarrow` is a shape, not an arrow in Ti*k*Z sense. It's a very, very old thing in the package. Also, the access of the internal inductance is somewhat limited because they are placed like nodes and not like bipoles. Maybe defining your own subcircuit could help, if you need them often.

Comment: What do you mean with "defining" your own subcircuit? Do you mean I should define my own shape for that purpose? And yes `currarrow` isn't a real arrow, but why does shortening the path introduce a new stroke?

Comment: The stroke thing is unexpected. I am looking into it.

Comment: That stroke is a bug. I am filling a not properly closed stroke. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have a couple of possibilities here. The first (my suggested one) is to use the transformer's anchor to add a voltage over an `open` bipole (that will maintain the general look of the voltages in the circuits). Like this:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core](pol) {};
    \draw ([xshift=0.2cm]pol.outer dot B2)
        to[open, voltage=straight, v=$v_2$]
          ([xshift=0.2cm]pol.outer dot B1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With this option, you can use also the techniques shown in "advanced voltages..." in the manual to have reference points where to put real Ti*k*Z arrows.

The other option, if you need to add several "decorations" to the single inductances, is to draw the transformer "manually" --- the double dipoles are there just as a convenience for the most common applications, but using two inductances is not difficult, and you have plenty of anchors to position them and the core lines.

On the other hand, the problem with the extra stroke is a bug in `circuitikz`: I (well, `circuitikz` authors) am filling a path without correctly closing it and it leaks somehow when `shorten` is used. I will try to fix it asap, but for now you can check with the workaround below.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{currarrow}{
    \savedanchor{\northeast}{%
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
        \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{current arrow scale}
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@circ@res@step
        \pgf@y=\pgf@x%
    }
    \anchor{north}{\northeast\pgf@x=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{east}{\northeast\pgf@y=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{south}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y \pgf@x=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{west}{\northeast\pgf@y=0cm\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
    \anchor{north west}{\northeast\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{south east}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{south west}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{tip}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
        \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{current arrow scale}
        \pgf@x  =\pgf@circ@res@step
    }
    \behindforegroundpath{
        \pgfscope
            \ifpgfcirc@really@draw@currarrow
                \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
                \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{current arrow scale}
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{-.8\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{.8\pgf@circ@res@step}}
                %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
                \pgfpathclose
                \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
                \pgfusepath{draw,fill}
            \fi
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core] (pol) {};
    \draw[shorten <=.5cm, red] (pol.B1) to node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} (pol.B2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core] (pol) {};
    \draw[blue] (pol.B1) to[shorten <=.5cm] node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} (pol.B2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notice however that `pos=1` still refers to the unshortened line (this is a Ti*k*Z thing, not `circuitikz`-specific) so probably the result is not the one you are expecting when using

```latex
\draw[shorten <=.5cm, shorten >=0.5cm, color=red] (pol.B1)
     to node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} (pol.B2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think for the double bipoles your first suggestion is pretty neat. For normal occurrences of such arrows, I'm not quite sure "advanced voltages..." looks nice (I didn't knew about this, so thanks for the hint/suggestion) but I think in most usages of mine it's not necessary to be able to modify the arrow that precisely (and if not necessary it clutters the code unneeded, but it's nice to know if once this is needed).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with the bug correlating to the use of `shorten`, I was already wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: > where to put real TikZ arrows

---- Just a note on that since it may be interesting for the developer, but actually sometimes it is indeed nice to not have a real tikz arrow, since this way it's pretty easy to move the arrow along the path (sometimes the arrow shouldn't be at the end of the path but rather in the middle)

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to shorten a line using calc notation.  One could also use `($(pol.B1)!.1!(pol.B2)$)` etc.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[transformer core] (pol) {};
    \draw[red] ($(pol.B1)+(0,-0.5)$) to node[currarrow,sloped,pos=1] {} ($(pol.B2)+(0,0.5)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: +1, but use `color=red`, not `red` (yes, I know. But it's documented at the start of the "color" chapter in the manual).

Comment: Well, thanks for writing and screenshotting, but that's kinda similar to the "quick and dirty" fix with my `skip` key (no offense). But I still wonder is why tikz is acting so weird with that extra line being drawn when using `shorten` and I'm wondering there is a nice way using the `shorten`  key correctly.